# how to use content_tag in a lib/class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my problem: I want to create a class TitlePanel in my lib folder that class uses the content_tag method but I can't figure out how to load it. I have tried all require 'xxx' that I could think of and it keeps giving me error messages that it can't find the required file.

Basically, what I am trying to do is create a helper that generates html, but I have to pass thru a class to store some value first. Ex of what I am trying to do:

```
title = TitlePanel.new("this is my title")
title.add_panel "help" do
  content_tag :div, "this is the help section..."
end
title.add_panel "search" do
   content_tag :div, "this is the search section..."
end

title.to_s
```

the output being all the required HTML to make this work.

Answer (score 16):

This is an old question, but I found this first and had the same trouble as OP. Best solution I found was to use this:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.content_tag(:div, nil, class: 'my_div')
```

Answer (score 12):

Give this a shot.  If you include TagHelper in at the top of your file in your lib directory, it should work.  Here's an example:

```
class MyLib
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

  def foo(x)
    content_tag :div, x
  end
end


>> MyLib.new.foo "bar"
=> "<div>bar</div>"
```

Comment: Situation improved a bit. It is now complaining about the missing method capture.

Here is my full code
    class TitlePanel
      include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  
      def initialize(t, d= "default")
        @title = t
        @description = d
        @labels = []
        @panel = Hash.new
      end

      def add_panel(label, &block)
        @labels << label
        @panel[label] = yield
      end
    end

Comment: improved formating but removed the .to_s method - crap, formating does not work for comments ?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on in your code sample.  But, if you just want to use the content_tag method within module in your lib directory, then you should be able to just add this bit to the top of your file:  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

Comment: I did it. But I am still getting the "undefined method `capture' for #<TitlePanel:0x1036ca198>" exception. Isnt requiring TagHelper supposed to get all of its dependencies?

Comment: Is it possible that when I yield the block that is passed to add_pannel, the block does not have access to the scope where content_tag is defined?

But even if this is the answer, it does not explain why I am getting the undefined method 'capture for ...' exception.

Comment: Try adding `attr_accessor :output_buffer` and set `@output_buffer = nil` in your initializer. It may be that the TagHelper methods just want you to keep track of the reference.